# What are the last three non-zero digits of $2015!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What are the last three non-zero digits of $2015!$

I feel confused, I've tried with mod $1000$, but it's useless.

Comment: well, i forgot to put non zero

Comment: See [her](http://learningroots.in/cat-and-omet/quant/last-non-zero-digit/) for useful hints

Comment: See here as well: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/71768.html

Comment: The problem of calculating $n! \pmod m$ for $n < m$ is known to be very hard (afaik unsolved in polynomial time).  This problem is basically asking "solve $n! / q \pmod m$ for $n > m$, with $q$ being a sufficiently large factor to prevent the product from devolving to zero".  It seems "obvious" (aka I can't prove it but seems provable) that this is a strictly harder problem than the first one I mentioned, so you aren't going to do better than just running a computer program, asymptotically.

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely doable without a computer or calculator, with a small computational effort (less than $100$ multiplications modulo $125$)

The numbers of trailing zeros in $2015!$ is equal to the exponent of $5$ in its factorization (since $2$ has a much larger exponent than $5$), which is:

$$\lfloor2015/5\rfloor+\lfloor2015/5^2\rfloor+...=403+80+16+3=502$$

If $x=\frac{2015!}{5^{502}}$, all the difficulty is to calculate $x\bmod 5^3$. If we would know $x\bmod 5^3$, then $2^{502}\bmod 5^3=4$ (follows easily from Euler's theorem $2^{100} \bmod 5^3=1)$, and its inverse modulo $5^3$ (using for example $4\cdot 31=-1 \bmod 5^3$).
This would give us the value of $\frac{2015!}{10^{502}}\bmod 5^3$. As we already know that $\frac{2015!}{10^{502}}\bmod 2^3=0$, the value of $\frac{2015!}{10^{502}}\bmod 1000$ would follow by the CRT.

To calculate $x\bmod 5^3$, we can use [Gauss's generalization of Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization). This gives $$\prod_{\substack{i=1\\ 5\nmid i}}^{5^3} i \equiv -1 \pmod {5^3}$$

So we can get rid of entire chunks of $125$ elements

We can get rid first of $2001\cdot...\cdot2015$. This gives $5^3$, and the rest of the factors are congruent to $74$ modulo $5^3$

From $2000!$ we can take out $5^{400}$, the product of the terms which are not divisible by $5$ is $1\bmod 5^3$ (Gauss), and we are left with $400!$

From $400!$ we can take out $5^{80}$, Gauss's theorem gives the product of the terms non-divisible by $5$ up to $375$ as being $-1\bmod 5^3$, and all that is left is to calculate $376\cdot377\cdot378\cdot379\cdot381\cdot...\cdot399\bmod 5^3$. Then we are left with $80!$

From $80!$ we can take out $5^{16}$. For the product $y$ of the terms non-divisible by $5$, we can calculate first $z=81\cdot82\cdot83\cdot84\cdot86\cdot...\cdot124$ and solve $y\cdot z\equiv -1 \pmod {5^3}$

Then $16!$ is manageable.

There may be more shortcuts that I haven't seen, and/or stronger theorems in number theory, but this is how I would have approached this problem, should I have lived a century ago.

Answer (score 1):

The last three non-zero digits are 544 (followed by 502 zeros). 
Computed using the online [Big Integer Calculator](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm).

Here is a one-line program *avoiding large numbers*:

m=1;for(k=2,2015,m=m*k;while(m%10==0,m=m/10);m=m%1000);print(m)

(PARI/GP)